# Redirecionamento desnecessário nas páginas

Tags: php

Olá.

Recebi um site já pronto em mãos. O que acontece é que não consigo abrir ele de jeito algum em meu localhost.

O que acontece é que quando abro a página localhost/index.php o browser gera o seguinte erro **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Ao abrir a index.php encontro logo de cara as seguintes linhas.

```
QApplication::Redirect("/");
exit();
```

Isso faz algum sentido? Logo no início da página existe um redirecionamento e uma finalização do script, sendo que a index.php tem 250 linhas de código. Porque será que isso está assim? Lembrando que isso é um backup e o site funciona em um servidor: http://www.aprendoemcasa.com.br

Comment: Você está rodando ele localmente com que programa? Eu uso o xampp, e pra poder acessar os sites, os projetos são separados por pastas dentro de "htdocs", no seu caso por exemplo, o projeto ficaria em _C:\xampp\htdocs\aprendendoemcasa_, aí sim acessaria através do navegador pelo link http://localhost/aprendendoemcasa. Verifique se no seu caso o projeto precisa estar em uma pasta assim também.

Comment: Estou usando o easyPHP, e ja desenvolvi diversos projetos com ele, isso nunca aconteceu.. Eu ja meio que forcei a entrada comentando diversas linhas no site, como o exemplo que dei a cima. No entanto este não é o certo a se fazer pois o projeto ja funciona da forma que chegou a mim. (funciona no servidor).